# take those rows where two cols are increasing simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a pandas/pyspark data frame say for example:

```
Name  Family  Area  age_tier   age_tier_num  diseases
N1     F1      A1   <=10       1             2
N1     F1      A1   11-20      2             3
N1     F1      A1   21-40      3             5
N1     F1      A1   41-80      4             2
N2     F2      A1   11-20      2             6
N2     F2      A1   21-40      3             1
N2     F2      A1   41-80      4             8
N3     F2      A2   <=10       1             8
N3     F2      A2   11-20      2             4
N3     F2      A2   21-40      4             6
N4     F3      A2   11-20      2             5
N4     F3      A2   41-80      4             7
```

Now grouping by Name, Family & Area  if diseases are increasing with age_tier_num, the only I will take it in my new data frame,for any age_tier_num diseases must be greater than all the previous ones.
So my output should be :

```
Name  Family  Area  age_tier age_tier_num  diseases
N1     F1      A1     <=10     1             2
N1     F1      A1     11-20    2             3
N1     F1      A1     21-40    3             5
N2     F2      A1     11-20    2             6
N2     F2      A1     41-80    4             8
N3     F2      A2     <=10     1             8
N4     F3      A2     11-20    2             5
N4     F3      A2     41-80    4             7
```

I need this to be done both in python pandas and pyspark. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: why is `N3  F2   A2   21-40   4    6` is row not retained?

Comment: for any age_tier_num diseases must be greater than all the previous ones. N3  F2   A2   21-40   4    6  here 6 is smaller than 8 of N3     F2      A2     <=10     1             8